# VBA : If combine Hlookup & Vlookup result 1 match another combine Hlookup & Vlookup result 2 then result1 cell font color

Tags: vba, vlookup

I do have below code which works fine for Hlookup & Vlookup part and provides correct values step by step. It returns values from 2 sheets.
However i am not sure how to get IF part working fine. Not sure if i am using result as reference in correct way?

I want to VBA highlight fonts to desire color if result xSM = result xNG.
[image]

```
Dim shSM, shAcNG as Worksheet 
    Set shSM = Thisworkbook.Sheets("SM")
        Set shAcNG = Thisworkbook.Sheets("AcNG")
Dim Hsm, Vsm, lrSM, lcSM as Long
    Dim xSM,xNG as Variant

lrSM = shSM.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
 lcSM = shSM.Cells(7, shSM.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Hsm = 2 To lcSM
    For Vsm = 3 To 44


HLvalueSM = shSM.Cells(1, Hsm).Value
    VLvalueSM = shSM.Cells(Vsm, 1).Value

xSM = Application.VLookup(VLvalueSM, shSM.Range("A3:EK44"), Application.HLookup(HLvalueSM, shSM.Range("A1:EK2"), 2, False), False)

    xNG = Application.VLookup(VLvalueSM, shAcNG.Range("A3:EK44"), Application.HLookup(HLvalueSM, shAcNG.Range("A1:EK2"), 2, False), False)


If IsError(xNG) Then
    shSM.Cells(xSM.Row, xSM.Column).Font.Color = vbRed
ElseIf xSM = xNG Then
        shAcNG.Cells(xNG.Row, xNG.Column).Font.Color = vbGreen
ElseIf xSM <> xNG Then
        shAcNG.Cells(xNG.Row, xNG.Column).Font.Color = vbRed
End If

Next Vsm
    Next Hsm
```

Comment: Vlookup returns a cell *value*, not a reference to the found cell.

Comment: @TimWilliams so how can i find reference of this particular results cells. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup returns a cell value, not a reference to the found cell.

Try this instead:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim shSM As Worksheet, shAcNG As Worksheet
    Dim Hsm As Long, Vsm As Long, lrSM As Long, lcSM As Long, clr As Long
    Dim cNG As Range, cSM As Range, ngCol, ngRow
    
    Set shSM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SM")
    Set shAcNG = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AcNG")
    

    lrSM = shSM.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    lcSM = shSM.Cells(7, shSM.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Hsm = 2 To lcSM
        For Vsm = 3 To 44
            
            Set cSM = shSM.Cells(Vsm, Hsm)
            
            'match in col 1
            ngRow = Application.Match(shSM.Cells(Vsm, 1).Value, shAcNG.Columns(1), 0)
            'match in row 1
            ngCol = Application.Match(shSM.Cells(1, Hsm).Value, shAcNG.Rows(1), 0)
            
            If Not IsError(ngCol) And Not IsError(ngRow) Then
                
                Set cNG = shAcNG.Cells(ngCol, ngRow) 'got a matching cell in shAcNG
                clr = IIf(cNG.Value = cSM.Value, vbGreen, vbRed)
                
                cSM.Font.Color = clr
                cNG.Font.Color = clr
                
            Else
                cSM.Font.Color = vbRed 'no matching cell
            End If

        Next Vsm
    Next Hsm

End Sub
```